# How to decrease linux box arp response?

Tags: linux, arp

I had known that I can not stop arp flood from others, so I wonder to know how can I decrease the response times per second, so that my cpu wont cost too much for arp flood, any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any measure that would do that (**Edit:** See below). As this is only an issue in connected networks you could either have static ARP entries and disable ARP learning (if feasible), or you report the attack to the network administrators and have them deal with the attacker.

**Update:**

You could use `ebtables` to limit the amount of ARP that reaches your system. `ebtables` has a `--limit` module for that. I'm not sure if that will decrease your CPU load. Please note that this could enable DoS as this may limit legitimate ARP traffic.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I find some router devices have this function to filter/decrease (just for themself) arp flood, so any tips?

Comment: You could use `ebtables`, see my updated answer.